# Vue authorization with Pinia - How do I get my functions to return values and not promises?

Tags: axios, authorization, vuejs3

I'm working on front end authorization with Vue and Pinia. My goal is to fetch a list of permissions belonging to the current user into my component file and then check if the User has the  permission to see certain aspects of my component.

*The problem arises when I use v-if to call my methods and check whether the user has the required permission. My function values are never returned and it always defaults to true.*

This is what my **auth.js** file looks like:

```
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
    id: "authentication",
    state: () => ({
        ...,
        ...,
        userPermissions: fetchUserPerm(), //!!!
)},

const fetchUserPerm = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("api/users/me"); 

// My Laravel back end returns a User object with a Role property 
which contains a list of all the permissions tied to this user:

    return res.data.role.permissions; 

};
```

And this is code contained within the **component** that I want to fetch the permissions to:

```
<script>
import router from "../../../router";
import axios from "axios";
import Modal from "../../UI/Modal.vue";
import { useAuthStore } from "../../../stores/auth";

export default {
    setup() {
        const authStore = useAuthStore();
        return { authStore };
    },

data() {
        return {
            ...,
            ...,
            userPermissions: this.authStore.userPermissions,
            filteredPermissions: null,
        };
    },
```

**I tried the following in "methods" and "computed" within my component:**

```
methods:{
    async checkUserPermFn(value) {

         this.userPermissions = await this.userPermissions;
         this.filteredPermissions = this.userPermissions.filter((permission) => {
                      return permission.name.includes(value);
                 });

          console.log(this.filteredPermissions); //CORRECTLY LOGS AFTER FILTERING:
             Proxy { <target>: [], <handler>: {…} }
                 <target>: Array []

          return this.filteredPermissions.length > 0; //Gets ignored
        },
}
computed:{
        async checkPermission() {
            
            this.userPermissions = await this.userPermissions;
            console.log(this.userPermissions,"computed"); //CORRECTLY LOGS :
                Proxy { <target>: (22) […], <handler>: {…} }
                     target>: Array(22) 

            this.filteredPermissions = this.userPermissions.filter(
                (permission) => {
                    return permission.name.includes('permission.name');
                }
            );
            console.log(this.filteredPermissions,"computed"); // CORRECTLY LOGS AFTER FILTERING:
                  Proxy { <target>: [], <handler>: {…} }
                  <target>: Array []

            console.log(this.filteredPermissions.length)// CORRECTLY LOGS 0

            return this.filteredPermissions.length > 0;
        },
    },
```

Now in my component I try check what gets returned from my methods and why does it still render them:

```
<div v-if="checkUserPermFn(value)"><p>Hi!</p></div>

This div is still shown even though the method should return false, and when I console log what my method returns I just get a promise: 
      Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
               <state>: "fulfilled"
```

Doing the same thing but with the computed method:

```
<div v-if="checkUserPermFn(value)"><p>Hi!</p></div>

The div is shown again even though the method should return false, and when I console log what my computed method returns I get a promise again but this time it contains the correct value too:
       Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: false }
​
                 <state>: "fulfilled"
```

What am I missing here? I tried resolving promises but that only works within the method, when I try to return the resolved value I get a promise again. Thanks everyone!

Comment: store state should always be static values (false, null, "someString", etc), not function calls that require execution.  set default value of `userPermissions` as something like null or false.  `fetchUserPerm` should then be an [action](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html) that you call when the user first logs in, loads the app, or other appropriate time when a user permissions should be fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I used your advice and made the API GET call and set my permissions in an action and also saved the permissions  in a cookie. 
However, my userPermissions value is still a function that returns the permissions which are pulled from the cookie to maintain state even after page refresh. Any idea how I could do this in a better way?